# Partial differential equation - regularity question

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded and $\partial\Omega\in C^{4,\gamma}$. I consider a boundary value problem in the form

$\begin{cases} 
\Delta^2 u(x)=f(x)-u|u|^{p-1} &x\in\Omega\\
u(x)=\Delta u(x)=0 &x\in\partial\Omega
\end{cases}
$

where $p\in [1,\infty)$ and $f\in C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$

Now let u be a weak solution to the problem ($u\in H^2(\Omega)\cap H^2_0(\Omega)$) and let u be bounded, meaning $u\in L^\infty(\Omega)$. Here comes my problem, which I even computed a while ago, but I just can't remember where it comes from.

One can find that then that

$$f(x)-u|u|^{p-1} \in L^\infty(\Omega)$$

and therefore $$f(x)-u|u|^{p-1} \in L^p(\Omega)$$ for $p\in [1,\infty)$.

Now from regularity in Sobolev spaces, we find that $$u\in W^{4,q}(\Omega)$$ for $q\in(n, \infty)$. Why not from $q\in[1,\infty)$? I think the argument should be simple and I've found it in multiple sources, but I just don't quite get it.

---

The question was not very clever to begin with, sorry. As suggested by ˈjuː.zɚ79365 in the comments, $q\in(n, \infty)$ is needed for the next step.

Comment: Sounds strange. Since $\Omega$ is bounded, the spaces $W^{4,q}$ are tested: $W^{4,n+1}$ is  contained in $W^{4,q}$ for $1\le q\le n-1$. One possibility is that the writer wanted to emphasize $q>n$ for some reason. It would help to know what followed the claim about $W^{4,q}$.

Comment: awww, stupid me, I was just editing my post above. Yes, in the next step I want the embedding $$W{4,q}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow C^{a,b}$$ with the highest $a$ possible. That would be $$C^{3,1-n/q}$$ and then $q$ needs to be in $(n,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that $q\in(n, \infty)$ is not needed in that step. It comes later from $W^{4,q}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow C^{a,b}(\Omega)$ where I need the highest regularity of the weak solution possible, $a=3$ and $b=1-n/q$.

Sorry for the confusion.